# certbot -d website.com throws apache2ctl configtest error

Tags: apache-2.4, lets-encrypt, certbot

I've made a couple scripts to easily set up a site on my Digital Ocean Debian machine. The script that secures the site basically just creates the `sites-availble` file, runs the certbot command, then prompts you to restart Apache. It's worked flawlessly before.

The command in the script that causes the problem:

`sudo cerbot -d mywebsite.com`

With the `--apache` flag it throws the same error.

The error I get

```
Error while running apache2ctl configtest.
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
AH00526: Syntax error on line 19 of
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mywebsite.ca.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file
'/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mywebsite.ca/fullchain.pem' does
not exist or is empty
```

The file in reference

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mywebsite.ca
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mywebsite.ca
        Redirect permanent / https://mywebsite.ca
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mywebsite.ca
        ServerName mywebsite.ca
        ServerAlias www.mywebsite.ca

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mywebsite.ca/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mywebsite.ca/privkey.pem
    #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>
```

Line 19 is `SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mywebsite.ca/fullchain.pem`

Some things from my apache2 error log

`AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/lib/letsencrypt/tls_sni_01_page/] does not exist`

`[Thu Aug 03 12:13:00.265826 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 12795] AH01906: 9113409597ce29a2adba7e6df41d732f.81d7a00618deb2e454817e363526c145.acme.invalid:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)`

There's an identical (except for the domain name) sites-enabled file for another domain that works fine.

I've tried a few variations of the certbot command with little luck, I'm nervous to try too much stuff because there's other live sites on this server.

What's causing this error and any tips on where to look to fix it?

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -l /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mywebsite.ca/`? I would start by comparing that to the similar `sites-enabled` setup with a working site (file permissions, owner, etc)

Comment: @Bert part of the issue is that it's not even getting that far, it's not creating/setting up the cert. That directory doesn't even exist.